# Capturing Ctrl+A shortcut key

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to capture a kepress combo on the keyboard so i can override the standard function, i've tried the following:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello");
    }
}
```

But when pressing `Ctrl+A` the message is not triggered. The end aim is to override the windows shortcut 'select all' in a `DataGridView` within the `Form1` to ensure only certain rows are selected when `Ctrl+A` is pressed in the form window.

Comment: try `e.Modifiers ==    Keys.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.A`

Comment: Assign  `Form1`'s `KeyPreview = true` property

Comment: Thanks that's the beastie, one note though...it didn't work at first because i set it under the Form KeyDown event and not the DataGridView KeyDown Event. It seems when a DataGridView is present in a form it automatically hooks the Ctrl+A shortcut. Please post your answer so i can select it as the solution ;)

Comment: @dmitry-bychenko thanks i guess that solves what i just described?

Answer (score 2):

First, ensure that `Form1` property

```
KeyPreview = true
```

Next, do not forget to *handle* the message (you don't want `DataGridView` process the message and do `SelectAll`)

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
    {
        e.Handled = true; // <- do not pass the event to DataGridView

        MessageBox.Show("Hello");
    }
}
```

So you *preview* `KeyDown` on the `Form1` (`KeyPreview = true`), perform the required action, and *prevent* `DataGridView` from executing *select all* (`e.Handled = true`)

Answer (score 0):

In general to handle a shortcut key, you can override [`ProcessCmdKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). By overriding this method, you can handle the key combination:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.A))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Control + A");
        return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Returning `true`, means it's handled by your code and the key will not pass to the child control. So it's enough to override this method at form level.

But if you are talking specifically about `DataGridView` to customize the `Ctrl + A` combination, you can override [`ProcessDataGridViewKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.processdatagridviewkey(v=vs.110).aspx) method of the `DataGridView`:

```
public class MyDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    protected override bool ProcessDataGridViewKey(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == (Keys.A | Keys.Control))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Handled");
            return true; 
        }
        return base.ProcessDataGridViewKey(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: To override `ProcessCmdKey` you *don't need* to set key preview.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the records: This can be done with `KeyPress` too, because the Ctrl+Letter keys are "special":

```
    private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.KeyChar=='\u0001') //Ctrl+A, B=2, C=3 ...
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Control + A");
        }
    }
```